# SQL - How to select x number of rows prior to a specific row

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have this table:

```
   ts  |  user_id  |   event   |  
-------------------------------
 1500        a         eat 
 1501        a         walk 
 1502        a         sleep 
 1500        b         eat 
 1501        b         sleep 
 1502        b         wake
 1500        c         walk 
 1501        c         eat
 1502        c         sit
 1503        c         sleep 
 1504        c         wake
```

So I want to select `x` number of rows prior to a certain event, let's say I want to select 2 events before `sleep` per user_id.

My final table result should look like:

```
user_id  |   event   |   rank  |
--------------------------------
    a         eat         1
    a         walk        2
    a         sleep       3
    b         NULL        0
    b         eat         1
    b         sleep       2
    c         eat         2
    c         sit         3
    c         sleep       4
```

How to do this in SQL (specifically Redshift SQl)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oraclce, sql-server...?

Comment: it's redshift sql as mentioned, I will tag it.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What if the same user sleeps twice? (2) You need a column to order the rows of each user, do you have such column?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a row before unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: 1. if user sleeps twice, still it has to display x number of event before each of the sleep event. 2. I am using `rank() over (partition by user_id order by date)` to order the row for each user.

Comment: adding timestamp column above for ordering purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(event) over (partition by user_id order by ts) as next_event,
             lead(event, 2) over (partition by user_id order by ts) as next_event2
      from t
     ) t
where 'sleep' in (event, next_event, next_event2);
```

Note:  This only returns rows that are in the data.  If you need for rows to be generated additional logic is needed.

EDIT:

You can actually generalize this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when event = 'sleep') over (partition by user_id order by ts rows between current row and 2 following) as cnt_sleep
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_sleep > 0;
```

This counts the number of "sleep"s in the next `n` rows (well, n - 1).  It returns a row if "sleep" is found in any of them.

Comment: What if i needed to have 3 previous events without  adding the additional column in the query?

Comment: still understanding the intuition but this looks simple enough to get to what I want.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for the answer. I am picking this as the answer closest to what I want. Plus if I want fixed number of event as columns (like event1, event2, event3) I think I can use the `lead` function?

Comment: @addicted . . . Yes.  Lead allows you to put data in neighboring rows into columns.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, where you want the first and the last two rows of each island.

Probably the safest approach is a window sum of the sleep events to define the group, and then filtering with `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by user_id, grp order by ts) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by user_id, grp order by ts desc) rn_desc
    from (
        select t.*,
            sum(case when event = 'sleep' then 1 else 0 end) 
                over(partition by user_id order by ts desc)  grp
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where (rn_asc = 1 or rn_desc <= 2) and grp > 0
order by user_id, ts
```

We define islands with a window count of "sleep" events in descending order. Then, we just enumerate each island rows in both ascending and descending order, and filter on the records we are interested in.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=92113348e7dfd15ee86ff8d350695f95)**:

```
  ts | user_id | event | grp | rn_asc | rn_desc
---: | :------ | :---- | --: | -----: | ------:
1500 | a       | eat   |   1 |      1 |       3
1501 | a       | walk  |   1 |      2 |       2
1502 | a       | sleep |   1 |      3 |       1
1500 | b       | eat   |   1 |      1 |       2
1501 | b       | sleep |   1 |      2 |       1
1500 | c       | walk  |   1 |      1 |       4
1502 | c       | sit   |   1 |      3 |       2
1503 | c       | sleep |   1 |      4 |       1
```

---

**EDIT**

Redshift requires a window frame in the `order by` clause of window functions. So it is a bit longer to type:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(
            partition by user_id, grp 
            order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and current row
        ) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(
            partition by user_id, grp 
            order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and current row
        ) rn_desc
    from (
        select t.*,
            sum(case when event = 'sleep' then 1 else 0 end) over(
                partition by user_id 
                order by ts desc
                order by ts rows between unbounded preceding and current row
            )  grp
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where (rn_asc = 1 or rn_desc <= 2) and grp > 0
order by user_id, ts
```

Comment: sorry I missed the column to order the event, I do have timestamp column to order the events.

Comment: when trying to run `select t.*,
            sum(case when event = 'sleep' then 1 else 0 end) 
                over(partition by yser_id order by id)  grp
        from mytable t`, I got  error `Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause`

Comment: @addicted: ah, yes, that's a bizarre limitation of Redshift. I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for that. I am trying out your query and trying to get the intuition now.

Comment: Hi @GMB thanks for the answer. I am choosing Gordon's answer as the answer since it's simpler and got to what I want.